# Set "left" attribute on a for loop name in C#

Tags: c#

```
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                int randomSpeed = RandomNumber(2, 10);

                 "apa" + i.Left -= randomSpeed;
            }
```

Look at the  `"apa" + i.Left -= randomSpeed;` this is wrong.

I have PictureBoxes that have names apa1, apa2 and apa3.

I would like to set the Left of the names apa+ i

How can i set the Left to the random speed in the loop for each of them?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have a finite number of controls, its probably easier to just do:

```
foreach (var control in new[] { apa1, apa2, apa3 }) 
{
    int randomSpeed = RandomNumber(2, 10);
    control.Left -= randomSpeed;
}
```

Comment: I get twice ; expected at the var control in new[]

Answer (score 3):

You will have to put them in an array. Plus `int`s dont have a `left` property.

```
PictureBox[] apas = new PictureBox[] { apa1, apa2, apa3 };

        for (int i = 0; i < apas.Length; i++)
        {
            int randomSpeed = RandomNumber(2, 10);

             apas[i].Left -= randomSpeed;
        }
```

Comment: He's trying to build up the name of the control "apa1" so he can do `apa1.Left`.

Comment: @Karem change it to `Length`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to alter the `Left` property of a control named ("apa" + i), right?

You could [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) the control:

```
(PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("apa" + i, true)[0].Left -= randomSpeed
```

Don't forget to add error checking.

Comment: You don't really need to cast result to PictureBox as you are setting property "Left" only and it is defined in Control